# Is there anyway for me to download a Linux distro for Aarch64 laptops?

Tags: linux, arm, arm64

I need to install a Linux distribution on my [ARM64 laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-flex-series/lenovo-flex-5g-14q8cx05/88lgf801419?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F&sortBy=priceDown#tech_specs), but it just won't work.
I have already tried several stuff and none of them work.

Can anybody point me out anything I could do?

I have already tried:

[Generic Arch Linux AARCH64](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/generic)

[Fedora ARM](https://arm.fedoraproject.org/)

[OpenSuse AARCH64](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:AArch64)

[Manjaro-ARM](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Manjaro-ARM)

[Fedora](https://arm.fedoraproject.org/)

[Aarch64-laptops](https://github.com/aarch64-laptops/debian-cdimage)

[Snapdragon 8cx Mobile Platforms](https://www.linaro.org/blog/upstream-linux-support-now-available-for-the-the-qualcomm-snapdragon-8-gen-2-mobile-platform/)

Comment: You are unlikely to get any help by saying it just doesn’t work. When you have tried to install what happens? Do you have issues installing? Does it install and not boot.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Sorry but "it just won't work" doesn't tell anything useful. Instead please describe what exactly happens - "When I do X I expect Y but Z happens instead". What exactly are you trying to install to, and how exactly is important. See the [guidelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on writing a question in the [Help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The devil's in the details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.